# how to use automapper to map datareader to a list of DateTime?

Tags: automapper

I use automapper to map data reader to objects and they worked really well.
However, when my query only returns one column which is DateTime:

```
select actionDateTime from @GenerateWeeklyTable
```

And I use automapper to map this to a list of DateTime object in c#

```
actionLogs.Dates = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<DateTime>>(reader).ToList();
```

I got error: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: con

So what is the right way to use automapper in this scenario?

Many Thanks

Comment: try IEnumerable<DateTime?> - allow nullable

Comment: same thing. I suspect that I need to somehow privide column name "actionDateTime" somewhere.

Comment: You can override it in mapping profile . E.g. http://elegantcode.com/2009/10/16/mapping-from-idatareaderidatarecord-with-automapper/

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from the DB array (IDataReader) using GetValue(0) and use ConvertUsing() to map each row to DateTime

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, DateTime>()
        .ConvertUsing((source, destination) => ((DateTime)source.GetValue(0)));
});
IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
IDataReader reader = <read data from DB>
if (reader != null && reader.FieldCount >= 1)
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> tDates = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DateTime>>(reader);
}
reader.Close();
```